# how to take desired value from the multiple same elements in the xml by using LInq c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am parsing an XML file that contains `<es:qrxlev>` nodes. Sometimes these nodes are found directly in the `<xn:attributes>` node, and sometimes they are found deeper, like in `<es:pciConflictCell>` and `<es:pciDictictCell>` nodes.

I am after the value of the `<es:qrxlev>` node directly in the `<xn:attributes>` node.

My XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xn:VsDataContainer id=test">
  <xn:attributes>
    <xn:vsDataType>vsDataEUtranCellFDD</xn:vsDataType>
    <es:crsGain>0</es:crsGain>
    <es:pciConflictCell>
      <es:enbId>66111</es:enbId>
      <es:qrxlev>3</es:qrxlev>
    </es:pciConflictCell>
    <es:pciConflictCell>
      <es:enbId>66111</es:enbId>
      <es:qrxlev>7</es:qrxlev>
    </es:pciConflictCell>
    <es:pciDictictCell>
      <es:enbId>66111</es:enbId>
      <es:qrxlev>8</es:qrxlev>
    </es:pciDictictCell>
    <es:pdcchLaGinrMargin>100</es:pdcchLaGinrMargin>
    <es:lbEUtranAcceptOffloadThreshold>50</es:lbEUtranAcceptOffloadThreshold>
    <es:pdcchCfiMode>5</es:pdcchCfiMode>
    <es:qrxlev>10</es:qrxlev>
    <es:zzzTemporary21>-2000000000</es:zzzTemporary21>
  </xn:attributes>
</xn:VsDataContainer>
```

and the code I'm using right now is:

```
List<XElement> vsDataEUtranCellFDD = vsDataContainers.Where(x => x.Descendants().Where(a => (a.Name.LocalName == "vsDataType") && ((string)a == "vsDataEUtranCellFDD")).Any()).ToList();

     List<CellName> cells = vsDataEUtranCellFDD.Select(x => new CellName()
                                                {
    if (vsDataEUtranCellFDD.Any()) 
    {
        List<CellName> cells = vsDataEUtranCellFDD
            .Select(x => new CellName() 
            {
                qrxlev= (int)x.Descendants()
                    .Where(a => a.Name.LocalName == "qrxlev")
                    .FirstOrDefault()
            };
    }
```

The problem with this code is that it returns *all* `<es:qrxlev>` node values, not just the one in the attributes node. How can I get only the specific value I want rather than all values?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Descendants()`, that gets all nodes in the tree. use `Elements()`, which gets the *immediate children* of the current node.

```
var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
    <xn:VsDataContainer id=""test"" xmlns:xn=""xn"" xmlns:es=""es"">
      <xn:attributes>
        <xn:vsDataType>vsDataEUtranCellFDD</xn:vsDataType>
        <es:crsGain>0</es:crsGain>
        <es:pciConflictCell>
          <es:enbId>66111</es:enbId>
          <es:qrxlev>3</es:qrxlev>
        </es:pciConflictCell>
        <es:pciConflictCell>
          <es:enbId>66111</es:enbId>
          <es:qrxlev>7</es:qrxlev>
        </es:pciConflictCell>
        <es:pciDictictCell>
          <es:enbId>66111</es:enbId>
          <es:qrxlev>8</es:qrxlev>
        </es:pciDictictCell>
        <es:pdcchLaGinrMargin>100</es:pdcchLaGinrMargin>
        <es:lbEUtranAcceptOffloadThreshold>50</es:lbEUtranAcceptOffloadThreshold>
        <es:pdcchCfiMode>5</es:pdcchCfiMode>
        <es:qrxlev>10</es:qrxlev>
        <es:zzzTemporary21>-2000000000</es:zzzTemporary21>
      </xn:attributes>
    </xn:VsDataContainer>";

XNamespace xnNamespace = "xn";
XNamespace esNamespace = "es";

var xmlElement = XElement.Parse(xml);
var qrxlev = xmlElement
    .Element(xnNamespace + "attributes")
    .Element(esNamespace + "qrxlev")
    .Value;
```

This will return `10`, the value of the fourth `<es:qrxlev>` element.

I had to make some modifications to your xml:

- You didn't declare any of your namespaces
- Your `test` attribute was improperly quoted

Comment: this is huge file and i am assigning the required parts in to c# classes and then taking it.Will this work with classes???

Comment: Maybe? I'd have to see your classes to know. But if you're doing xml parsing with XElement, which it looks like you are, the it _should_ be fine. Go try it out.

Comment: I am geting error like value cannot be null if i use like qrxlev= (int)x.Element(un+"cellId")

Comment: with the existing code is there any way i can find immediate child value

Answer (score 0):

If you want the highest-level definition, make a method to find node's level in the tree, like this:

```
static int GetDocLevel(XElement e) {
    var res = 0;
    while (e != null) {
        res++;
        e = e.Parent;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Now you can sort by level, and take the top one:

```
XNamespace esNs = "http://www.es.org"; // <<== The actual namespace goes here
var topQrxlev = doc.Descendants(esNs + "qrxlev").OrderBy(GetDocLevel).FirstOrDefault();
```

Here is a running example:

```
class Program {
    static int GetDocLevel(XElement e) {
        var res = 0;
        while (e != null) {
            res++;
            e = e.Parent;
        }
        return res;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
<xn:VsDataContainer
    xmlns:es=""http://www.es.org""
    xmlns:xn=""http://www.xn.org""
>
<xn:attributes>
  <xn:vsDataType>vsDataEUtranCellFDD</xn:vsDataType>
  <es:crsGain>0</es:crsGain>
  <es:pciConflictCell>
    <es:enbId>66111</es:enbId>
    <es:qrxlev>3</es:qrxlev>
  </es:pciConflictCell>
  <es:pciConflictCell>
    <es:enbId>66111</es:enbId>
    <es:qrxlev>7</es:qrxlev>
  </es:pciConflictCell>
  <es:pciDictictCell>
    <es:enbId>66111</es:enbId>
    <es:qrxlev>8</es:qrxlev>
  </es:pciDictictCell>
  <es:pdcchLaGinrMargin>100</es:pdcchLaGinrMargin>
  <es:lbEUtranAcceptOffloadThreshold>50</es:lbEUtranAcceptOffloadThreshold>
  <es:pdcchCfiMode>5</es:pdcchCfiMode>
  <es:qrxlev>10</es:qrxlev>
  <es:zzzTemporary21>-2000000000</es:zzzTemporary21>
</xn:attributes>
</xn:VsDataContainer>";
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        XNamespace esNs = "http://www.es.org";
        var topQrxlev = doc.Descendants(esNs + "qrxlev").OrderBy(GetDocLevel).FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(topQrxlev?.Value); // Prints 10
    }

}
```